# Highcharts: How to provide a custom stack label in highcharts bar graph from within the stackLabel formatter?

Tags: highcharts

For the past two days I've been trying real hard to figure out a way on how to provide a custom stack label instead of using the this.stackTotal option.

My Scenario is, the label for each stack is not basically dependent on each series but rather a multitude of factors. Therefore the client wants to set an arbitrary value to the end of each stacked bar. What I have so far is this (http://jsfiddle.net/yybLxgkd/) but have been unsuccessful so far in trying to display a custom label at the end of each stacked bar.

I tried to pass-in the value that I needed to be displayed at the end of each stack from within the series by providing a series option called QTotal, but later I realized that the stackLabel does not support (this.point.series). So I tried to play around and get atleast the category name displayed at the end of each bar but this too has been in complete vain.

I would really appreciate any help I can get in trying to resolve this issue.

Once again, what I what I would like to accomplish is display a custom label for each stack rather than (this.stackTotal) option.

My logic was perhaps I could initiate a loop for all the categories, from the stackLabel formatter, that are present and depending on the category - display the arbitrary value that is needed.

Many Thanks,
Jerry

My code is below:
$(function () {

```
var categoriesVal = {
    'Term 1':'Term 1',
    'Term 2':'Term 2',
    'Term 3':'Term 3',
    'Term 4':'Term 4',
    'Term 5':'Term 5'        
};
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
                    style: {
                                      fontFamily: 'Geneva, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif'
                                }                       
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Serious AEs',
                    style: {
                    fontSize:'1.2em',
                    fontWeight:'bold'
                    }    
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Term 1','Term 2','Term 3','Term 4','Term 5'],
              //    lineColor:'#000',
                    lineWidth:.5,
                    tickWidth:.5,
                    tickLength:3,
                    tickColor:'#000',
                    title: {  
        text: '',
        style: {
            color:'#000',
            fontSize:'.8em'
        }
    },
    labels: {
        style: {
            fontWeight:'bold'
        }
    }
},
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
                    //lineColor:'#000',
                    lineWidth:.5,
                    tickWidth:.5,
                    tickLength:3,
                    tickColor:'#000',
                    //gridLineWidth:0,
                    //gridLineColor:'#eee',                   
            title: {
                text: 'Total',
                          rotation:0,
                          style: {
                                      color:'#000',
                                      fontSize:'.8em'
                                      }
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                   // color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                },
                          formatter: function() {
                         // var s = this.series.options.QTotal;
                          //      return Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.round(s*100)/100,2)+'%';

                return categoriesVal[this.value]+' Test';
                          }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -70,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
                    //shared: true,
                    crossHairs: true,
                    //useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y + this.point.dtLabel; /*+'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal*/;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                                /*formatter:function(){
                                      return this.point.dtLabel;
                                },*/
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
              {
            name: 'Not Serious',
                  data: [{y:2,dtLabel:'<br />Subject(s):0012001,006007'},6, 3, 3, {y:4,dtLabel:'<br />Subject(s):0012001,006007'}], 
                    color: '#000000',
                    QTotal:0.79
        },
              {
            name: 'Serious Severe',
            data: [0,0,0,2, 5], 
                    color: '#FF0000',
                    QTotal:0.79
              },
              {
            name: 'Serious Moderate',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1], 
                    color: '#00FF00',
                    QTotal:0.79
        },
              {
            name: 'Serious Mild',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2], 
                    color: '#0000FF',
                    QTotal:0.79
        }                 
              ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

The stack label `this` doesn't contain a reference back to its series because it's a combination of all the series; so I'm not sure how you'd map a series QTotal to each stack.

The easiest way to do this would be to place your custom property directly into the `stackLabel` options:

```
stackLabels: {
    qTotals: ['This','is','a','qTotal','!'],
    enabled: true,
    style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    formatter: function() {            
        return this.options.qTotals[this.x];
    }
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yybLxgkd/2/).